# Best way to make a medical history DB in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, nosql

i'm making a sistem that stores all medical , and healthy data from a person in a database , i've chosen mongodb to do the work but i'm new in mongodb modeling and i dont have an idea of whats the best way to do this.

Do i use a document for each pacient and insert subdocuments  like this:

```
 $evolution=array(); //subdocument
 $record=array(); //subdocument
 $prescriptions=array(); //subdocument
 $exams=array(); //subdocument
 $surgeries=array(); //subdocument
```

or do i create a new document for each one of these data?.

i know the limitation of document size that is 16 megabytes, but i don't know if the informations will reach the limmit.

Comment: In MongoDB database modeling, the most important consideration is how you query your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact layout of your documents is highly dependent on the types of queries you need to make.  Unfortunately without a detailed understanding of your use case it would be impossible to provide good advice about what is the best layout.

Depending on your use case it may be valid to have a document/patient with sub documents as you indicate.  In some cases though it may be better to have a separate collection for each of the fields indicated.  It all depends on how big those documents will be, what types of queries you will need to perform etc.

Some general advice:

- Try to avoid queries that use multiple collections.
- If your queries are getting difficult, you may have the wrong layout.  Re-evaluate your layout any time you are in this situation.
- Documents that constantly grow can create problems because Mongo constantly has to move them around in order to make room for the growth.  If they will be growing quickly then reevaluate to see if there is a better layout.
- While you can technically store different document layouts in the same collection in Mongo it is not generally considered a good practice.  All documents in your collection should ideally follow some sort of schema even if that schema is not rigidly defined.
- Field names matter.  They take up space in Mongo so short field names are better if you expect to have a lot of data.

The best advice I can offer would be to start with what you think might work and see how it goes.  If it gets awkward or difficult to get the information you need then reevaluate.